# Is this bug on my wisteria harmful?

Tags: pests

I recently found this bug underneath the leaves of my wisteria.

[image]

There were a few of them and they seem pretty attached to the plant (i.e., stayed put when I moved the leaves). They have also laid eggs underneath the leaves, which have hatched. I sprayed them all away. I have tried to identify this insect but it doesn’t seem to fit the description of any of the common pests on wisteria (e.g., aphids, mealybugs, scales, white flies).

Can anybody please tell me what they are and if I should be worried for my wisteria? Thanks!

Comment: On which continent do you live? It might be a black aphid or a parasitoid wasp, hard to tell from this image.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I live in Western Europe

Comment: I think it is a black aphid with wings, if I see it correct there is a little black stripe at the bottom of the wings, just like this image [here](https://ucanr.edu/sites/KACCitrusEntomology/Home/?repository=67829&a=47581).

Comment: Thank you so much!